# How to Enable/Disable/Edit Alsa Audio's 32 Channels?

Tags: linux, alsa

We are trying to develope a linux Version of our Application which is used for real-time Video Compositing. I understand that Alsa audio gives you 32 channels by default on Audio to use for different routing of input and outputs.
The question is, how and where you can edit or disable these 32 channels. In our UI we have a volume meter for the different available audio channels for the user to use as reference for volume. Now the software shows 32 channel meters, since it sees 32 channels in Alsa. It doesn't make a difference which Audio Interface we are using (Integrated audio interface, or USB external, etc...) It always shows 32 available channels.
We are using Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon.

Comment: This appears to be a peculiarity of the Linux Mint configuration. Try adding the `SND_PCM_NO_AUTO_CHANNELS` flag to `snd_pcm_open()`.

Comment: I found the snd_pcm_open() definitions flags under usr/include/alsa/pcm.h but I cannot read or write in the file. I suppose that means reinstalling the libraries and providing the read and write permissions at that point?

Comment: No, you should change the call to `snd_pcm_open()` in your program.